# Aptana sh.git.log hangs when run in IDE

Tags: python, git, aptana, sh

[file: foo.py]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sh
import os

cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print cwd
sh.git.bake(_cwd=cwd)
print sh.git.status()
print sh.git.log('-n 1', '--pretty=%H')
```

Really simple bit of code, but in the IDE, when it gets to

```
sh.git.log('-n 1', '--pretty=%H')
```

Everything just hangs, this happens if I run, or debug the file.  When I run this in the command line with 'python foo.py' or './foo.py' the script completes in less than a second, with the exact same output from the

```
sh.git.status()
```

Command, but additionally with the output from the log output too.

I've tried delving into what might be happening in the background with sh and git, but by it's very nature it's incredibly 'generic', thread-happy and hard to follow the logic trail.

I'm on
 Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5,
 Aptana Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137,
 Pydev 2.7.0.2013032300
 Python 2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but the log command is probably trying to page results and is waiting for  stdin, try the following to turn off the pager:

```
git = sh.git.bake("--no-pager", _cwd=cwd)
git.log('-n 1', '--pretty=%H')
```